# How to ignore code when data does not contain necessary values?

Tags: r, na

I'm very new to R and here as well and need some help fixing my code because sometimes my data gets weird

So I have data similar to this

```
Random  Price
11.23   0.68
66.77   0.51
68  0.46
78  0.51
88  0.32
89  0.51
90  0.27
91  0.65
```

This is my code so far:

```
newdata <- data[ which(data$Random>=30
& data$Random < 50), ]
Pvalue<- lapply(1:length(dat), function(i){
if(length(dat[[i]][[4]])>1){
t.test(newdata$Price,dat[[i]][[4]])$p.value 
}else 'not enough observation'
})
```

My code basically does a t.test between the data from `'newdata'` and another set of data called `'dat'`
But there are times when I don't have `data` from 30 to 50 similar to my example data above.
So instead of my code returning an error, how could I change it so that it just returns `NA` .

Comment: What is `dat`, is that a typo? DO you mean `newdata`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You already know how to use the `if/else` construct. All you have to do is add one testing `nrow(newdata)`, or maybe combine both as follows:

```
newdata <- subset(data, Random >= 30 &
                        Random < 50)
Pvalue <- lapply(dat, function(x){
  if (length(x[[4]]) > 1 & nrow(newdata) > 1) {
    t.test(newdata$Price, x[[4]])$p.value 
  } else NA
})
```

You could also replace `lapply(...)` with `sapply(...)` or `vapply(..., numeric(1))` to get a numeric vector instead of a list. For that, it is recommended to replace `'not enough observation'` with `NA` like I did, or you could end up with a character vector.

Comment: why not  nrow(newdata) > 0 ? to get enough observation in the t.test..?

Comment: +1.you're right. In the code of `t.test`I get this  `if (nx < 1 || (!var.equal && nx < 2))`..

Comment: thanks for this...I forgot that I could just that '&' function